# How are floating point operations handled in php

Tags: php, floating-point

I'm aware of the errors with loss of precision that can happen with floating point errors. But I'm not really sure of when and how it's using floating point representations. I feel like my question is best represented by the following shell session:

```
php > $a = 819.94 - 61.67;
php > $b = 758.27;
php > echo $a;
758.27
php > echo $b;
758.27
php > echo $a == $b;
php > echo (string)$a == (string)$b;
1
php > var_dump($a);
double(758.27)
php > var_dump($b);
double(758.27)
```

How is this even possible?

Specifically, how are the string representations being determined? == is supposed to be typeless compare. I don't see how casting before comparing should change the values at all.

Also, the var_dumps are showing me an identical value. It doesn't seem unreasonable for me to expect that if the value returned by 2 var_dumps are identical, that the 2 values should be equal.

Comment: well, it doesn't use a float-datatype when you *cast it to a string*, but converts it to a string according to its *precision*-setting.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann If the values are not equal, then when converted to a string, why did it not show me 758.2666666666666666666669 or something. I'm converting to a string AFTER the floating point operation. NOT BEFORE

Comment: have you read the word *precision-setting*? have you heard of *rounding*? internally, you got something like 758.2699999999999 and 758.27000000000001 - round them to 5 digits, you get 758.27000 for both, which is then shortened to 758.27

Comment: @Cruncher - the key words in Franz's answer were `according to its precision-setting`

Comment: And the [PHP Docs are very clear about comparing floats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker Okay, and that's the kind of stuff I'm looking for in a real answer. Why is this getting downvoted and close voted? This is clearly an unintuitive result

Comment: @MarkBaker None of that documentation says ANYTHING about why the string representations are showing equal.

Comment: No, that doc link is why comparing floats directly gies you false; for why casting to string and comparing gives true, you need the docs on type juggling from float to string, and to remember those magic words `according to its precision-setting`

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm fully aware of why float conversion gives problems. But when I var dump both values and it returns the same looking object this is *obviously* confusing, and a seemingly uniquely php thing. I'm sorry for not knowing all the little intricacies of PHP, but isn't this what stackoverflow is **for**? For example, the given answer is extremely useful. You linking to some documentation that clearly doesn't answer the question isn't.

Comment: Tip: PHP Extentions for MATH are found here http://php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php and where made because of the behavior of default math stuff from php.

Comment: Also : http://www.php.net/floatval & http://www.php.net/doubleval   and in php is float==double read here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two base facts:

- Numbers in one base do not necessarily have an exact representation in another base.
- Floating point numbers are specifically designed to lose precision in order to accomplish wider ranges.

So when you have a base 2 IEEE floating point number (`$b = 758.27`) and you want to convert it to a finite base 10 representation (`(string)$b`) it's obvious that you have to implement some rules.

In PHP, one of the rules is to only display up to [precision](http://php.net/precision) digits:

> `precision integer`
>       The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers. -1 means that an enhanced algorithm for rounding such numbers
>   will be used.

```
var_dump(ini_get('precision'), 758.27, 819.94 - 61.67);
ini_set('precision', 20);
var_dump(ini_get('precision'), 758.27, 819.94 - 61.67);
```

```
string(2) "14"
float(758.27)
float(758.27)
string(2) "20"
float(758.26999999999998181)
float(758.2700000000000955)
```

Comment: Okay, this is very helpful, but I'm confused for other reasons now. Without changing my precision-setting, if I assign "123.4567" to a variable, and echo that it displays all 4 decimal places. Likewise it will display `double(123.4567)` in the var_dump. If the precision just has to do with the "display" and not the "value", then shouldn't it apply to all floating point numbers?

Comment: That's another rule: not print leading and trailing zeroes /// [Online demo](https://3v4l.org/qGKGc)

Comment: Oh, it's being cut off in the middle of the sea of 0's(or 9's) you mean? And thus then has to cut out the 0's? That makes sense

Comment: `var_dump(1.12345678901234567890)` gives me `double(1.1234567890123)`. That makes me much more satisfied now. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes. Neither `var_dump()` nor type casting are designed to provide full fledged number formatting. You have dedicated functions for that, from [printf()](http://php.net/printf) to [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php).

Comment: And not setting `precision` yourself doesn't mean that none is used. It just means it'll use the system default, which can be changed in many different places.

Comment: Yep, I get it now. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I will say finally, that it seems absolutely ridiculous to me that VAR_DUMP doesn't show you the full value. This all would have been completely cleared up for me if var_dump ignored precision. Because it says double(758.27), with no mention of strings. How was I supposed to know that it was based on string conversion rules?

Comment: What would be the alternative? A base 2 number can be periodic in base 10. Printing infinite digits can take a while. Would an hexadecimal dump of the memory registries be more helpful?

Comment: I mean, it should show me the exact representation that it has for the variable of course. I get that the floating point VALUE has a precision. I'm saying var_dump should show you the value with THAT precision. Not the string conversion precision. That is, show me what the hell the value is. var_dump is supposed to be a debugging tool.

Comment: Since `var_dump()` cannot violate the laws of physics, the only way to print `1.01` accurately would be something like `0x3f8147ae` ([source](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), not necessarily the actual value in PHP). Would you prefer that?

Comment: A fraction would be useful actually. They are rational numbers after all. Just some way to indicate that the values are in fact different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136377/discussion-between-cruncher-and-alvaro-gonzalez).

Comment: `1.01` is in fact a carefully chosen example. Let's say you're been assigned to the `var_dump_improved()` design group. Feel free to post the expected output for `1.01`.

Comment: "A base 2 number can be periodic in base 10." This isn't true. Any binary floating-point number has a finite (possibly long, but nevertheless finite) base-10 representation.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You're right, the conversation got lengthy and accuracy suffered.